# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xctest

I am getting following exception when trying to integrate a library to my project using cocoa pods.

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
  Referenced from: /Users/shoaibahmedqureshi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBC381BC-854F-41D6-8D4C-90C2850459AD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/095CDEFA-A79A-4235-B046-68277D5C14EB/EasyGridExample.app/EasyGridExample
  Reason: image not found

I have myself created that open source library so I am open to tweaks and suggestions to that library as well in case issue lies there.

Github link to Project : https://github.com/shoaibahmedqureshi/EasyGridsExample

Github link to Library : 
https://github.com/shoaibahmedqureshi/EasyGrids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.clean and build
2.delete DerivedData  folder

make sure you have add your library in embedded binaries

Comment: I never thought that the solution would be that simple. thanks btw

Answer (score 9):

Please make your XCTest framework optional in General under target Linked Frameworks and Libraries and then try.
[image]

Comment: Was stuck on this for days, this solved my problem thank you @rizwan!

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Comment: Was this renamed? I'm using XCode 12.3 and cannot see a field called "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" under "Target -> General". I see "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content".

Comment: What did work for me was to go to "Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries" and set XCTest to optional there.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it happened because I mistakenly put Nimble and Quick pods in my main target instead of in my unit test target. So just double check your pods, try to uninstall one by one.

Comment: I changed it on podspec to the test section

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. In my case **RxTest** was in the main target, which was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and fixed by deleting the Podfile.lock and install pod again.

Answer (score 0):

I also saw something similar happen after accidentally copy&pasting a `@testable import MyModule` into a file outside of the Testing scheme. Replacing it with just the expected `import MyModule` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused if you include `XCTest.framework` under `Link Binary With Libraries` for a target that is **not** a testing target.

Accordingly, if you try to link a framework that *itself* depends on `XCTest` (e.g. if you have a framework with some test helper methods - `FooTestHelpers.framework`) to a non-testing target, you should only include `FooTestHelpers.framework` in the `Link Binary With Libraries` section for your **test** targets, not for any normal targets.

Check the `Referenced from:` line of the error message to identify the offending framework that's likely been incorrectly linked against a non-testing target.