# iOS crash in testFlight on open

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, testflight

When running the app in test fight it crashes upon opening.
The app runs well if tested directly in the simulator or on the device.

I did clean, archive and upload the app again and there was no difference.
The Valid Architecture is set only to arm64

This is the error in the console

```
Attempt to add an app with insufficient id, info {
BKSApplicationStateAppIsFrontmost = 1;
BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "org.mydomain.name";
SBApplicationStateKey = 8;
SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = 677;
SBMostElevatedStateForProcessID = 8;
}
```

The app is build in react-native

React Native Environment Info:

```
System:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
  CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Memory: 3.59 GB / 16.00 GB
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 8.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
  npm: 6.1.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 12.0, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0
  Android SDK:
    Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.2, 25.0.3, 26.0.2, 27.0.3
    API Levels: 16, 19, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003
  Xcode: 10.0/10A255 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: ^0.56.0 => 0.56.0
npmGlobalPackages:
  create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native-rename: 2.2.2
```

I have fallowed the guid for release from here
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Is this the first time you tried uploading the app on TestFlight, or you had it working previously and now it doesn't work? Can you use Xcode  to Archive your app (and upload it on AppStore for testing) and see if you get any errors there?

Comment: This is the first time using TestFlight (uploaded multiple builds, that have the same issue). I've uploaded only using Archive from Xcode and then Distribute.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I had a similar problem after updating to Xcode 10.  The way I resolved it was to go to Xcode --> File --> Workspace/Project settings and choose "Legacy build system" and archive again

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, unfortunately it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns the crash was because of a framework '@rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest' not being loaded, and the errors I got in the console were misleading.

I was able to see the reason after submitting the app for beta review and getting back the crashlogs.

To fix this I deleted the derivedData folder and added XCTest framework in Liked Frameworks as optional. [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041666/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-xctest-framework-xctest)

Answer (score 2):

That could be signature or bitcode problem. First, you can regenerate your certificate and provisioning profile, create new build and upload it to TestFlight again. Then, if that didn't work, you can disable bitcode in project setting and create new build. The thing is when bitcode is `ON` TestFlight rebuilds apps before distribution.

Comment: The bitcode was already set to NO. 
I've regenerated the distribution certificate and provisioning profile, it still crashes in flight test. Any other suggestions?